# How to handle Qt5 close event for termination?

Tags: c++, qt, events, qt5

I have an application, which consists of two, apparently independent windows. Window A loads the data and shows some log, state info; opens Window B, where interactive processing takes place. To prevent accidental closing, in B I have an event handler, shown below. It works fine, however, it also prevents Window A to close it upon termination. Is there a better method, than using a public slot in B, and send a message through it by A, that now window B can really be closed? (or to distinguish terminating the application and closing one of the windows?)

```
void B::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
     QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("Application"),
                 tr("Can only be closed through closing the main window.!"),
                     QMessageBox::Ok );
        event->ignore();
}
```

Comment: Window A could call a method in B (something like `close(true)`) so B knows it must be closed when `void B::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable close button of one window by modifying its window flags